# Can you connect to xrdp by host name?

Tags: remote-desktop

I installed xrdp so that I can connect to my laptop from Windows machines on my network. I was able to connect to it once by it's IP address. But I can't seem to connect to it using it's host name. In Microsoft Remote Desktop I type the output from the "hostname" command, but it fails to connect. Is this a problem on my end or something with the network?

Comment: Have you tried *ping hostname* from windows' cmd? You did not share error message or exact behavior during connection attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should be able to use hosthame in order to connect to your remote computer through xRDP as long as you nave a name resolution system in place...(i.e. system that maps hostname to IP address on your network)

If you linux machine has been set with **a fixed ip address**,  you could modify the host file
(located under c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) and add a line 
**IP_ADDRESS      HOSTNAME**

```
Note : you need to open the notepad with admin rights in order to be able to save the changes in the host file
```

If you are using a DHCP server,  Ip address received by the Linux machine might change over time... and the host file approach might not be practical....A better option would be to use a DNS server where the DHCP can dynamically update the DNS entry

Hope this help
Till next time